# Different notations for definite integrals

Tags: calculus, notation

I've seen an integral being written in the more conventional way, i.e. $$\int_a^bf(x)~dx$$but I've recently come across another notation, $$\int_{[a,b]}f(x)~dx$$and I was wondering under which circumstances would you use the second notation, and whether or not it is a widely accepted notation? Any input is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I would use the first for a signed (ie. the usual Riemann integral), and the later for an unsigned integral (ie. Lebesgue integral).

Comment: Always is accepted (the second), but in general, is for the Lebesgue-integral

Comment: This is used for the *Lebesgue integral* , which is an integral on *sets*, and has direction for integrating.

Comment: More generally, $\int_{S} f(x) dx$ for some set $S$.

Comment: In France, it's possible to use the first one as a Lebesgue integral.